# USING IF WITH OUTER APPLY IN MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to write **IF** conditition in **OUTER APPLY**. I need to return more than one column so i don't want to write subqueries

```
SELECT name FROM v_users 
OUTER APPLY
(
    IF CAST(reg_date AS DATE)<CAST('03/25/2017' AS DATE)
   SELECT gender,email,age,class FROM tb_register_old WHERE id=v_users.user_id;
ELSE 
   SELECT gender,email,age,class FROM tb_register_new WHERE id=v_users.user_id;
)s
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: How to write IF conditition in OUTER APPLY to use different queries??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
SELECT name FROM v_users 
OUTER APPLY
(
 SELECT gender,email,age,class 
 FROM tb_register_old 
 WHERE id=v_users.user_id and CAST(reg_date AS DATE)<CAST('03/25/2017' AS DATE)

 UNION ALL  

 SELECT gender,email,age,class 
 FROM tb_register_new 
 WHERE id=v_users.user_id and CAST(reg_date AS DATE) >= CAST('03/25/2017' AS DATE)
)s
```

Comment: Thanks guy it is really good solution but I need to use IF condition.Is it possible?

Comment: @Axmed This is the result you need, why do you insist on using `IF`? You can not use `IF` within a query anyway.